# Changing base class in a inheritance hierarchy

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class structure like

```
class A:
    def method1(self):
        return 1

class B:
    def method2(self):
        return 2

class C(A,B):
    def method3(self):
        return self.method1()+self.method2()
```

The Classes `A` and `B` provide functionality which class `C` gathers and enriches with some wrappers. Now it happens that I need a similar class `C2` which is derived from a different implementation `A2` instead of `A`: `class C2(A2, B)` with the same `method3`.

How would you realize such a design (`C` can derive from different implementation classes)?

If it has to do with advanced Python programming (meta-classes?) an example would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If you need another class that inherits from a different base class, just define your new class so it inherits from that base class.

Comment: I don't want to copy and paste the code of method3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CMixin:
    def method3(self):
        return self.method1()+self.method2()

class C1(A,B, CMixin):
    pass

class C2(A2,B, CMixin):
    pass
```

Though the design you describe sounds like you want aggregation instead:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method3(self):
        return self.a.method1() + self.b.method2()


c1 = C(a1, b)
c2 = C(a2, b)
```

Comment: This was my first thought. Simple is better.

Comment: Oh. Somehow I wasn't aware that I can use methods that aren't in the base classes yet :)